# What is the best ajax control to display floating windows?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup, ajaxcontroltoolkit, overlay

Aloha,

I'm looking for a floating div type of control, to display another (user)control over an aspx page, using ASP.NET and Ajax. As far as I can see the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/) doesn't have a nice overlay control. Can anyone point me at a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a modal dialogue, then

In the AJAX toolkit, there is the [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx)

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) is a JQuery modal.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the BlockUI using jQuery:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/index-old.html#overview

It is an element that's "floating" ontop of an aspx page, it thats what your looking for?